# how to rename tab android use tabhost and long click

Tags: android, android-tabhost, rename, android-tabs

I have designed an app in that I am using Tabhost and I have added two tabs. I want rename tab `Device1` when "long click" this tab. I try some way but it is not working. I have implemented following:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Device1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="80px" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Device2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="80px" >

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  package com.example.renametab;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
  import android.widget.TabHost;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec tabDevice1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Device1");
    tabDevice1.setContent(R.id.Device1);
    tabDevice1.setIndicator("Device1");

    TabSpec tabDevice2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Device2");
    tabDevice2.setContent(R.id.Device2);
    tabDevice2.setIndicator("Device2");
    tabHost.addTab(tabDevice1);
    tabHost.addTab(tabDevice2);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //How to rename tab????
            //I try this way but it is false
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.Device1);
            tv.setText("New Name Tab");
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On close inspection using the Android Studio debugger, each tab contained in TabWidget is a LinearLayout with 2 children:

1. An `ImageView` with the id `android.R.id.icon`;
2. A `TextView` with the id `android.R.id.title`.

Knowing this, we can find each tab's title TextView, set an OnLongClickListener on each tab, and then modify the title using TextView.setText().

Here's my Fragment's onCreateView() method, defining 3 tabs, each implementing this functionality:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1).setIndicator("Tab 1").setContent(R.id.tab_1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2).setIndicator("Tab 2").setContent(R.id.tab_2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3).setIndicator("Tab 3").setContent(R.id.tab_3));

        LinearLayout tabOne = (LinearLayout) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0);
        final TextView tabOneTitle = (TextView) tabOne.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        LinearLayout tabTwo = (LinearLayout) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1);
        final TextView tabTwoTitle = (TextView) tabTwo.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        LinearLayout tabThree = (LinearLayout) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2);
        final TextView tabThreeTitle = (TextView) tabThree.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        tabOne.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                tabOneTitle.setText("New Tab 1");
                return true;
            }
        });

        tabTwo.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                tabTwoTitle.setText("New Tab 2");
                return true;
            }
        });

        tabThree.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                tabThreeTitle.setText("New Tab 3");
                return true;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here are before and after screenshots documenting the results:

[image: Before the long press on Tab 1]

[image: After the long press on Tab 1]

Comment: Can you explain how I can do the same when there is n number of tabs and also the tab count changes dynamically

Comment: You can probably do something like `int numTabs = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();` then use a for loop to get each tab, find its title text, and set its long click listener.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `onTabChanged` event:

```
TabHost th = new findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
th.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) th.getCurrentView();
    tv.setText("New Name Tab");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="204dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
         android:text="TAB 1"/>
```

Add a TextView in both the linear layouts in the xml file and set their text dynamically using Tab Change Listener :-

```
TabHost tabHost = new findViewById(android.R.id.tabHost1);
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
  public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentView();
    textView1.setText("This Tab is Selected");
  }
});
```